# cast list to another type and change variable of each element of it

Tags: vb.net

I have the next class: `SearchResultWithDetails`.

It inherits from `SearchResult` that implements `ISearchResult`.

In addition, I have a list of `ISearchResult` that is called `result`.

I want to cast the result into `SearchResultWithDetails` and set `ShortDescription` to be the same value as `DetailsText`.

`ShortDescription` and `DetailsText` are variables of the result.

I tried something like:

```
results.Cast(Of SearchResultWithDetails).ForEach(Function(item)
                                                 item.ShortDescription = item.DetailsText)
```

But it doesn't change the variable of `ShortDescription` to be the same as `DetailsText`.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [option strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) **On** you'll see that the [ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) method is not an *extension* method, it's actually part of the [List<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class. This method accepts an `Action<T>` aka. sub, not a `Func<T>` aka. function. Apply all these fixes and the code should look like this:

Single-line:

```
results.OfType(Of SearchResultWithDetails).ToList().ForEach(Sub(item) item.ShortDescription = item.DetailsText)
```

Multiline:

```
results.OfType(Of SearchResultWithDetails).ToList().ForEach(
    Sub(item)
        item.ShortDescription = item.DetailsText
    End Sub)
```

Comment: I got this exception:

Unable to cast object of type 'Match.SearchResult' to type 'Match.SearchResultWithDetails'.

Comment: You need to use `OfType` instead if `Cast`, I've updated my answer.